# Roteamento com o parâmetro "id" termina em página branca

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova, angular-providers

Quando eu faço roteamento com o parâmetro id termina em página branca.
http://denertroquatte.com.br/app

Meu app se inicia aparece as postagem, assim que eu clico na postagem ele vai para a outra página e "era para aparecer o conteúdo" mas fica tudo em branco.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'inicio.html'
    })  

    .when('/sobre',{
        templateUrl: 'sobre.html'

    })

    .when('/post/:postId',{
        templateUrl: 'post.html',
        controller: 'mostrarPost'
    })

});



//Aqui que se encontra o problema.
app.controller('mostrarPost', function($scope, $routeParams, $http){


$http.get('http://www.denertroquatte.com.br/database.php').success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
              if (item.id_postagem == $routeParams.postId)

                $scope.i = $scope.items[$routeParams.id_postagem]

            });
        });

});
```

E aqui segue o da Listagem:

```
app.controller('listagemPost', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('http://www.denertroquatte.com.br/database.php')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.items = data;
     });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código parece estar ok.

Você poderia replicar o comportamento no [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Pois assim fica mais fácil para quem quiser ajudar.

Pode fazer o `.get` só do `json` que é retornado do banco.

**EDIT**

Parece que você estava definindo o parâmetro do `$routeParams` de forma errada no controlador `mostrarPost`. O objeto `$routeParams` tem como propriedades os mesmos parâmetros definidos no `$routeProvider`, ou seja, se você definiu na sua rota que o nome do parâmetro é `postId`, então esse será o nome pelo qual esse parâmetro ficará acessível no `$routeParams`.

---

O seu `$scope.items` recebe um objeto com a propriedade `json_objs` que possui os seus posts, assim:

```
{"json_objs":[...]}
```

Logo, o seu `$scope.i` do `mostrarPost` deve receber algo como:

```
$scope.i = $scope.items.json_objs[$routeParams.postId]
```

---

Você também precisará colocar as referências do template `post.html` de acordo com o objeto retornado pelo seu `$get`, já que os nomes não estão de acordo com as propriedades dos objetos retornados.

Comment: Precisa ser no JsFiddle?

Subi a aplicação no servidor http://denertroquatte.com.br/app

Obrigado!

Comment: Quando for pedir mais informações sobre a pergunta/problema, use a área de comentários. 
Utilize o botão responder, apenas quando for responder uma pergunta.

Comment: Jean não deu certo. Continua com o mesmo problema =/